# Run one module in main thread in otherwise Angular webworker project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, web-worker

Let's have a project in angular. For performance reasons, we want the app to run in webworkers, this is okay as Angular team have a possibility to do it.

---

Our application needs want to implement a DOM manipulating library (google maps). We therefor need to make this module run on main thread, where DOM manipulation is possible. However we still want to do all of the heavy work in a webworker.

To minify this problem I contained all call to the external library to a single file. For convenience this file is module's service.

```
map
 - component.ts
 - service.ts
 - module.ts
 - template.html
 - styles.css
```

---

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(private mapService: MapService, element: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2)
        this.mapService.element.then(map => {
            renderer.appendChild(element.nativeElement, map)
        })
    }
}
```

---

```
@Injectable()
export class MapService {
    private static worker = new Worker('./worker.js')

    public map: google.maps.Map
    public element: Promise<Element>

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        const div = document.createElement('div')
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(div, { ... })
        this.element = new Promise(resolve => {
            //  Fetch google map div element as soon as it is availe
            google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(this.map, 'idle', () => {
                resolve(this.map.getDiv())
            })
        })
        MapService.worker.postMessage({ name: 'init', data: ... }])
        MapService.worker.addEventListener('message', event => { ... })
    }
}
```

The `template.html` only contains `<content></content>`. The component asks service for map element from external library, it is a `div`, this div is then added via `renderer.appendChild(element.nativeElement, div)`. The function `renderer.appendChild` is safe, but I am not sure if the DOM element, would be able to pass be passed to worker.

Questions to answer:

- How to run one module/service in main thread in webworker Angular app?
- Append element of external library to component template.
- Make inner components run on webworker

---

Notes:

- Whole app run in shadow DOM, uses `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`
- App is created via Angular CLI

Comment: Web workers are there to perform computationally expensive tasks that don't need DOM. They don't support DOM. That's why we still use main thread. If your code involves DOM, it isn't suitable for workers, end of story.

Comment: @estus I know, I don't want to do DOM manipulation in the component, but I haven't found a way to explicitly disable one module from using webworkers, as it seems to me right now, the option is only for whole project.

Comment: You have to stop thinking in terms of modules/services. The script that runs in web worker is a different app, can't use anything related to DOM. If it uses some things (services) from your main app, then these things should be common modules that are shared among these apps. Worker app should be separately bundled. There should be multiple apps (bundles) per project. I don't use CLI for that so I'm not sure what's the best way to handle multiple apps there. You can check this article https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135 for some ideas on the setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think angular doesn't have default support for running some of module in web worker and some in main thread. The default support available in angular is to run all your business logic (component and services) in web worker thread using "platform-webworker" and "platform-werbworker-dynamic" modules.
To work with this solution you need to make sure that your application does not have any direct references to window, dom, document etc in your component and services.

If it is difficult to modify existing application to make it compatible for web worker, you can still use web worker for running some of your cpu intensive code/logic in web worker thread and rest of the application can keep running in main thread.

Here is a presentation that talks about, how to do this:
[Web Workers In Your Angular Application](https://www.slideshare.net/SureshPatidar2/web-worker-in-your-angular-application)

Source code of the examples from the presentation for 
[Angular 5](https://github.com/patidar-suresh/angular5-webworker) and
[Angular 6](https://github.com/patidar-suresh/angular6-webworker)

Hope you will find this helpful.

Comment: Also running Angular in a worker is deprecated for some time now...